# addition to an int in multidimensional array

Tags: python

I feel really dumb but how do I locate an element of an array and add one to it? The problem is adding items and quantities to a shopping cart. So i need to add one to quantity which is the second input. i.e. multi-array would contain [item][quantity]

```
else:
    print ("That item is already in your cart")
    add = input("Want to add one more to your cart?")
    if add == "yes":
        addItem(strChoice)



def addItem(strChoice):
    #TO DO
    #Find the strChoice in the aryCart and then add one to the qty 
    for i in strChoice:
      aryCart = [strChoice][i+1]
```

Comment: You need to include more of your code.  Where is your array defined?

Comment: starts as aryCart = [] and then later aryTemp.append(strChoice)
       aryTemp.append(int(input("How many?")))
       aryCart.append(aryTemp)

Answer (score -1):

Some things to note:
Yes, you need to present with extra code, this is an example.
aryCart needs to be a dictionary and not an array.
Below is an example, how it needs to be done.

```
aryCart = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':2}
print(aryCart)
def addItem(strChoice):
    #TO DO
    #Find the strChoice in the aryCart and then add one to the qty 
    for i in aryCart:
        if(i == strChoice):
            aryCart[i] = aryCart[i]+1

print ("That item is already in your cart")
add = input("Want to add one more to your cart?")
strChoice = input()
if add == "yes":
    addItem(strChoice)  # Whatever your strChoice is 

print(aryCart)
```

Comment: did you even test / run this example?

Comment: Yes, by simply having the value of strChoice

Comment: but your ode you pasted gives a `NameError` since you dont define `strChoice` anywhere

Comment: That is why, i added the comment, #Whatever your strChoice is

Comment: ah ok i see. you could replace the `for` and nested `if` with a single `if` statement like `if strChoice in aryCart: aryCart[strChoice] += 1`

Comment: Yes, true. That is ideal case to use. Thanks